# Cloning with javascript - renaming ID of form elements within a table

Tags: javascript, clone

I have some code I am using that works well cloning the contents of a div as many times as needed.

The original code would rename the name/id of each form field. so the first clone the name would be "name1" second clone "name2" etc...

The problem is when I put the form fields within a div or a table for design purposes.

The code doesn't rename the form fields anymore as it seems to refer to the top elment which is the table or div (depending which I used)

Here is a cut down version of the code that contains everything needed for this example (can be copied into an editor and will work as is. You will see the field id's are not being renamed):

www.jsbin.com/oyavez/1/edit

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
var formCounter = 0;

function init() {
    document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;
    moreFields();
}

function moreFields() {
      formCounter++;
        var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + formCounter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;
</script>

<title>Add Orders IO TOC</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--  Template -->

<div id="readroot" style="display: none">


<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"><h3>Order <script>document.write(formCounter);</script></h2></td></tr>
<tr><td>Order ID: </td><td><input type="text" id="OrderID  name="OrderID[]" ></input></td>
<td>Order Name: </td><td><input type="text" id="OrderName" name="OrderName[]" ></input></td>

</table>
<br /><br /><input type="button" value="Remove Above Order" style="width:200px;"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

<!-- ROW -->

</div>

<!--  END Template -->

<!-- Start of form -->
<form method="get" action="form.php">

<table>
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><h2>Contract</h2></td></tr>
<!-- Static part of the form not to be cloned -->

 <tr><td>Contract: </td><td><input type="text" id="Contract" name="Contract" ></input></td>
 <td>Signed Date: </td><td><input type="text" id="datepicker0" name="SignedDate" ></input></td>

 <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><h2>Orders</h2></td></tr>

</table>

<!-- ROW -->

<!-- Cloned parts of the form appear here -->


<span id="writeroot"></span>
<table>
<tr><td align="center" >    <input type="button" style="width:200px;" value="Add another order     below" onclick="moreFields()" /></td>
<td align="center" ><input type="submit" value="Submit IO and all Orders" style="width:200px;"  ></td></tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Anyone know how to get to the child of the table it would seem?

Thanks!

Comment: First things first - your HTML markup is invalid (there's div opening tag missing, and input tag doesn't have separate closing tag). Setup a working example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle to get help faster.

Comment: I just edited the code, seems some code went missing when I posted the question. Is it still invalid and if so what is wrong?

Comment: Anyone - is there an easier way to paste code when asking a question? Like putting it within a tag to indicate it is code instead of four spaces for each line? :)

Comment: Paste the code, highlight it, and press the "Code" button above. It will auto-indent 4 lines. Also remember you need a blank line above your code block too.

Comment: when you paste your code part into editor there is a {} symbol on the top. just select the code portion and click on that icon . it will indent your code ..

Comment: There's no such thing as `<input name="blablabla"></input>`, closing input tag is suppose to be done like `<input name="blablabla"/>`

Comment: No...this is still valid like `<input name="blablabla"></input>`

Comment: Here is the code:
http://jsbin.com/oyavez/1/edit
And the output
http://jsbin.com/oyavez/1/